# Selenium works when started locally, but not remotely

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-chromedriver, codeception, supervisord

I'm hoping this is a simple issue to solve:

I have a dedicated machine that runs selenium with chromedriver. I can physically walk to the machine and type the following in a local terminal:

`java -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver=chromedriver238 -jar selenium-server-3.11.jar`

I can then go to any other machine on the network and kick off testing (in my case, codeception on jenkins) and it will sucessfully run my tests in chrome without a hitch.

However, if I try to run the above command without physically being at the selenium machine (ex, trying to ssh into the machine to run the command or making this command run as part of a supervisor process) then selenium has trouble starting the instance of chrome.

Has anyone run into this scenario before? Is there a way I can give 'interactive' access to the background script to allow it to open stuff on my screen?

Comment: Update the question with the exact `trouble starting the instance of chrome`?

Answer (score 1):

Because when you physically walk to the machine and run the command. the selenium can get the desktop/window interface.

When use SSH, selenium lost the desktop/window interface, selenium have to start chrome under headless model, but your code not config to run as headless model. So the conflict come out.

you need to config your code to run with headless model.

Comment: This doesn't really work for me, I don't want to run selenium headless because XVFB gives me different results to the actual browser.. and I can run a background task on the physical computer and it still fails :(

Comment: So you need to install virtual display like xvbf or xServer on your machine and config the virtual display will start for every remote ssh login terminal.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid the use of Xvfb because more tests fail under headless in comparison to using a screen.

Comment: Xvbf can supply a virtual screen, so that you can run under headful model.

Answer (score 0):

I'm to getting the same scenario, when i try to start the selenium code on the machine A it works yet when i try to start selenium and run the scripts from machine B
(remotely connecting to machine A using ssh [ssh test@machine-a]) chrome instance doesn't start/launch and driver is getting null.

logs :

> 2020-02-27 12:04:27,319 INFO  [LogWritter] Exception in beforeclass chrome driver instantiation , driver is null
>
> 2020-02-27 12:04:27,493 INFO  [LogWritter] Exception in getting screenshot---java.awt.AWTException: headless environment

Any help/suggestion would be great !